# Group of units of direct sum of rings is isomorphic to direct sum of the groups of units

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, group-isomorphism, direct-sum

Let $R_{1}$, $R_{2}$, $\cdots$, $R_{m}$ be rings with identity. **I need to prove that the following group isomorphism holds:**

> $U(R_{1} \oplus R_{2} \oplus \cdots \oplus R_{n}) \simeq U(R_{1}) \oplus U(R_{2}) \oplus \cdots \oplus U(R_{n})$.

I surmise that induction is going to be necessary here, but I'm having trouble even just getting started to prove it for just the base case, where $n = 2$:  $U(R_{1} \oplus R_{2}) \simeq U(R_{1}) \oplus U(R_{2})$.

I have absolutely no idea where to begin, so any kind of point in the right direction would be appreciated. Just be willing to answer lots of follow-up questions, please.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This is probably not the kind of answer you're looking for (which is why I'm not posting it as an answer), but $U$ is a right adjoint (to the group ring functor), and so automatically preserves products.

Comment: @RCT yeah, I'm not even sure what a "right adjoint" is, so doesn't really help me much.

Comment: No problem. Ask yourself: how is the multiplication defined on the direct sum? What is the identity element in the direct sum? What, then, does it mean to be a unit in the direct sum? I think when you write out all these definitions explicitly, you will see the claim quite clearly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Keep in mind that for a finite number of rings, the finite direct sum is isomorphic to the finite direct product. It is easier, then, to think of $R_1 \times R_2$ rather than of $R_1 \oplus R_2$. In particular, the elements of $R_1 \times R_2$ are pairs of the form $(r_1, r_2)$, the multiplication is $(r_1, r_2) (s_1, s_2) = (r_1 s_1, r_2 s_2)$ and the multiplicative neutral element is $(1,1)$.

It then follows easily that $(r_1, r_2)$ is invertible in $R_1 \times R_2$ if and only if there exist $(s_1, s_2) \in R_1 \times R_2$ such that $(r_1, r_2) (s_1, s_2) = (s_1, s_2) (r_1, r_2) = (1,1)$, which is equivalent to saying that $(r_1 s_1, r_2 s_2) = (s_1 r_1, s_2 r_2) = (1,1)$, which in turn is equivalent to saying that $r_1 s_1 = s_1 r_1 = 1 \in R_1$ and $r_2 s_2 = s_2 r_2 = 1 \in R_2$, which finally is equivalent to saying that $r_1$ is invertible in $R_1$ and $r_2$ is invertible in $R_2$.

Comment: what does this have to do with isomorphism, though?

Comment: @ALannister: What the argument above shows is not merely an isomorphism, but an equality: $U(R_1 \times R_2) = U(R_1) \times U(R_2)$.

Comment: say I really, really, really wanted isomorphism, though. Could I set up one that would do more or less the same thing as equality?

Comment: @ALannister: Equality *is* an isomorphism - the best available one, in fact! If $A=A$, then obviously $A \simeq A$ and the isomorphism is $f:A \to A$, $f(x) = x$.

Comment: because what you're doing I guess is taking an element in $U(R_{1} \times R_{2})$, say $(r_{1},r_{2})$, and you're saying that by definition, then, for any $(s_{1},s_{2})$, we must have that $(r_{1},r_{2})(s_{1},s_{2}) = (s_{1},s_{2})(r_{1},r_{2}) = (1,1)$, which is equivalent to saying that $(r_{1}s_{1},r_{2}s_{2}) = (s_{1}r_{1},s_{2}r_{2})=(1,1)$. Just so I understand this, was this part establishing that $U(R_{1} \oplus 
R_{2}) \subseteq U(R_{1})\oplus U(R_{2})$?

Comment: @ALannister: Exactly. And because I work only with logical equivalences, I also get the opposite inclusion, in the same time.

Comment: okay. Got it. Then, of course, it's induction time.

Comment: okay, so in the course of the induction, say my induction hypothesis is that $U(R_{1} \oplus R_{2} \oplus \cdots R_{k}) \simeq U(R_{1}) \oplus U(R_{2}) \oplus \cdots \oplus U(R_{k})$, how would this come into play in showing $k+1$? It seems like it wouldn't because in order to show $k+1$, you could just do exactly the same thing you did for the base case. Unless the induction comes in when applying the isomorphism?

Comment: @ALannister: Asume it for all $i \le k$ and then prove it for $k+1$ with: $$U(\color{blue} {R_1 \times \dots \times R_k} \times R_{k+1}) = \color{blue} {U(R_1 \times \dots \times R_k}) \times U(R_{k+1}) = \color{blue} {U(R_1) \times \dots \times U(R_k)} \times U(R_{k+1})$$ where we have used the induction hypothesis once for $i=2$ and once for $i=k$.