# Multiplicative inverses of $\Bbb Z \times \Bbb Z$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, inverse

This is more of a clarification.. I know the only multiplicative inverses of $\Bbb Z$ are $\{-1, 1\}$. I want to say that by the same principle, the only multiplicative inverses of $\Bbb Z \times \Bbb Z$ are $\{(-1, -1), (1, 1)\}$.

I can't seem to convince myself that $\{(-1, 1), (1, -1)\}$ should not be included here.. should they be?

TIA

Comment: Yes, they should be.  If $R$ and $S$ are rings with identity and $R^*$ denotes the group of units, then $(R \times S)^* = R^* \times S^*$.  This is a good exercise, though not hard.  And, it answers your question.

Comment: @randall of course, because right as joints preserve limits! :)

Comment: Got to be careful of those as joints.

Comment: @copper.hat dang ruined my joke with autocorrect

Answer (score 0):

Note that they are actually their *own* inverses: $(-1,1)\cdot (-1,1)=(1,1)$ which is the identity.

Comment: And presumably OP really was looking for *units*.

Comment: @Lubin yes, that’s the way I understood it.

Answer (score 0):

The unit group of a direct product is the direct product go its unit groups, see here:

[Group of units of direct sum of rings is isomorphic to direct sum of the groups of units](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2191471/group-of-units-of-direct-sum-of-rings-is-isomorphic-to-direct-sum-of-the-groups)

So $$U(\Bbb{Z}\times \Bbb{Z})=U(\Bbb{Z})\times U(\Bbb{Z})=\{(\pm 1,\pm 1)\}.$$